# How to constantly update stamina system

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a stamina system where if the player holds <kbd>Shift</kbd> they lose stamina.

I have it where every time <kbd>Shift</kbd> is pressed they lose some but *how do I make them constantly lose stamina?*

For instance every second they lose 3 instead of only losing 3 on the key press.

Here's the current code I have for it.

```
     //running
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = speed + run_speed;
        Stamina = Stamina - 3;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = speed - run_speed;
        Stamina = Stamina + 3;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code you can declare a boolean `bool isRunning` on the class and have it set to `true` when you run.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speed = speed + run_speed;
    // Stamina = Stamina - 3;
    isRunning = true;
}
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{
    speed = speed - run_speed;
    // Stamina = Stamina + 3;
    isRunning = false;
}
```

Add this to your update function

```
private void Update(){
    if (isRunning) { Stamina -= 3 * Time.deltaTime }
    else { Stamina += 3 * Time.deltaTime }
}
```